# Presenting Landscape UIViewController Modally Changes Layout of Parent

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller

In my iOS app, I need to present a landscape only view controller modally on top of a portrait-only view controller. The portrait-only view controller consists of a view controller with an embedded table view controller. To force the landscape view controller to be landscape, I added the following code to it:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

Then, from the portrait-only view controller, I modally present the landscape only view controller. Unfortunately, when dismissing the landscape only view controller I find that the layout of the portrait-only view controller is altered. Specifically, the table view's content offset has changed and the dynamic cell heights are thrown off.

When I removed the code forcing the landscape only view controller to be landscape, these changes did not occur...opening and closing the modal view resulted in the parent view's layout staying exactly the same.

How can I present the modal view controller as landscape without it altering the layout of its portrait-only parent?